# Rundeck job with Ansible's dynamic inventory (ec2.py)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, inventory, rundeck

How do I configure Rundeck in a way that I can execute a job through Ansible over a couple of AWS Ec2 instances? I am using Batix plugin but i believe that it is not configured properly or some personal configuration is missing.

My idea is to trigger a job from Rundeck without defining static inventories on Rundeck and Ansible, if possible. (I add that Ansible + ec2.py and ec2.ini works properly without Rundeck)

**Below a snippet of my the configuration file of inventory settings.**

- project.ansible-generate-inventory=true
- resources.source.1.config.ansible-gather-facts=true
- resources.source.1.config.ansible-ignore-errors=true
- resources.source.1.config.ansible-inventory=/**{{ VAR }}**
- resources.source.1.type=com.batix.rundeck.plugins.AnsibleResourceModelSourceFactory

for VAR I tried these values = **etc/ansible/hosts** ..... **/ec2.py** ..... **/ec2.py -- list** ..... **/tmp/data/inventory**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Dynamic inventory under Rundeck, take a look at [this](https://github.com/Batix/rundeck-ansible-plugin/issues/101) GitHub thread. Another way is to create a node source like [this](https://everythingshouldbevirtual.com/ansible-generate-rundeck-inventory/). Alternatively, you can use the Rundeck EC2 plugin to get directly the AWS EC2 nodes. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-ec2-nodes-plugin#rundeck-ec2-nodes-plugin).

Comment: Thanks for the links!