# Rundeck configuration for dynamic inventory

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, rundeck

I have configured rundeck and ansible on the same ec2 server in my admin account in aws and trying to get dynamic inventory from couple of different accounts into rundeck using the inventory file below

```
plugin: aws_ec2
regions:
  - us-east-1
  - us-west-2
assume_role_arns:
  - 'arn:aws:iam::prod1accountnum:role/ansible'
  - 'arn:aws:iam::prod2accountnum:role/ansible'
hostnames:
  - private-ip-address
keyed_groups:
  - key: tags.Name
    separator: ''
compose:
  ansible_connection: '''ssh'''
  ansible_port: 22
  ansible_shell_type: '''cmd'''
  ansible_ssh_common_args: '''-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'''
  ansible_user: '''Administrator'''
  ansible_ssh_private_key_file: |-
    { 'vpc-0123xxxx': '~/.ssh/prod1.pem',
      'vpc-0456xxx': '~/.ssh/prod2.pem'
    }[vpc_id]
```

Using above inventory file from my local, I am able to get the inventory list and also run commands against those ec2 servers like this

> ansible tag_server1 -i ec2.yaml -m win_ping

> ansible-playbook get-logs.yaml -i ec2.yaml --extra-vars "path=/temp/"

How do I use the same inventory file to pull the inventory list into rundeck and run jobs against them?

So far in Rundeck I tried going into Project Settings->Edit Nodes->Add New Node Source
and did this

[image]

I have the pem files added in the server as well but that is not populating the inventory into rundeck. Also, just used the File option as the node source and pointed it to inventory file but no use there as well.

I also used the ec2 plugin and imported nodes from AWS directly using assume role and now I can see the nodes but when running a job and pointing to the playbooks added in the ansible/rundeck server, I get below error

```
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available 
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring:all 
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available 
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring:prod1-server 
[WARNING]: No hosts matched, nothing to do
```

prod1-server is the server I selected using the node filter option in the job, so I see that the server exists but can't run any jobs against them. Can somebody point me to what I'm doing wrong with the first and second with dynamic inventory file and AWS inventory?

Adding the project config file for reference.

```
#Mon Jan 29 18:10:58 UTC 2024
#edit below
project.ansible-binaries-dir-path=/usr/local/bin/
project.ansible-executable=/bin/bash
project.ansible-generate-inventory=true
project.ansible-inventory=/etc/ansible/hosts.yml
project.ansible-ssh-passphrase-option=option.password
project.description=
project.disable.executions=false
project.disable.schedule=false
project.execution.history.cleanup.batch=500
project.execution.history.cleanup.enabled=false
project.execution.history.cleanup.retention.days=60
project.execution.history.cleanup.retention.minimum=50
project.execution.history.cleanup.schedule=0 0 0 1/1 * ? *
project.jobs.gui.groupExpandLevel=1
project.label=Team Jobs
project.later.executions.disable=false
project.later.executions.enable=false
project.later.schedule.disable=false
project.later.schedule.enable=false
project.name=team-jobs
project.nodeCache.enabled=true
project.nodeCache.firstLoadSynch=true
project.output.allowUnsanitized=false
project.retry-counter=3
project.ssh-authentication=privateKey
project.ssh-keypath=/home/ubuntu/.ssh/team/
resources.source.1.config.ansible-binaries-dir-path=/usr/local/bin/
resources.source.1.config.ansible-disable-limit=true
resources.source.1.config.ansible-gather-facts=false
resources.source.1.config.ansible-ignore-errors=true
resources.source.1.config.ansible-inventory=/etc/ansible/hosts.yml
resources.source.1.type=com.batix.rundeck.plugins.AnsibleResourceModelSourceFactory
service.FileCopier.default.provider=sshj-scp
service.NodeExecutor.default.provider=com.batix.rundeck.plugins.AnsibleNodeExecutor
```

Appreciate your time and help! tia

Comment: Hi! Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60095744/10426011

Comment: @MegaDrive68k yes, I basically did what I'm supposed to but maybe I'm missing something here because the inventory file works when I use it from my local but not from rundeck

Comment: Also, try turning off the Gather Facts on the Ansible model source, probably you're facing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77182201/no-nodes-discovered/77182376#77182376. Another thing, make sure to configure the node executor, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60019714/10426011

Comment: Thanks for the response @MegaDrive68k but turning off Gather facts didn't help with populating nodes using dynamic inventory. Edited the question to add my project config file for reference. Please let me know if that makes sense

Comment: I see, did you check this? https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/ansible-plugin/issues/101#issuecomment-419749639